# How can I achieve this image effect iOS (look at picture)

Tags: ios, image, effect

Hey guys I'm building an iphone app where I show a listing with a couple images and information, just like the app store. Now I'm trying to achieve an effect like this one : [image]

Take a look a the app images, they have like this nice "3D feeling" and also some shadows. How can I achieve this? Is there any framework out there that makes this process simple? It doesn't need to look identical but I want to a find a way to make my logos be more sharp and shiny.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it's called CoreAnimation.

If you want to, for example, give a shadow effect to an UIView instance, use this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8, 8);
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.667;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "shiny" effect is a lot easier to achieve now that you can do Core Image filters on iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html

Comment: Thanks! Which filter would you recommend for achieving the effect? Do you know any resource where I can find examples of the filters being applied?